# Selenium Python : find element whose href attribute has required keyword

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The page I'm working on is in **[this link](http://www.ema.europa.eu/ema/index.jsp?curl=pages%2Fmedicines%2Flanding%2Fepar_search.jsp&mid=WC0b01ac058001d124&searchTab=searchByKey&alreadyLoaded=true&isNewQuery=true&status=Authorised&status=Withdrawn&status=Suspended&status=Refused&keyword=abilify&keywordSearch=Submit&searchType=name&taxonomyPath=&treeNumber=&searchGenericType=generics)**.

This is the relevant portion of that page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    ...
    <div id="searchResults">
      <div class="box-related">...</div>
      <a href='downloadDataServlet?category=true&amp;type=epar' onclick=""><img src="/ema/images/icon_download_spread.gif" />Download results to spreadsheet</a>
      <div class="table-holder">
        <table class="table-epar eparResults" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="Search results for EPARs ordered alphabetically">
          <caption>EPAR Search results</caption>
          <thead> ... </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="key-detail name word-wrap">
                <a href="index.jsp?curl=pages/medicines/human/medicines/000471/human_med_000619.jsp&amp;mid=WC0b01ac058001d124">Abilify</a>
              </th>
              ...
            </tr>
            <tr>...</tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the XPath location of the element I wish to select:

```
//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th/a
```

But there may be many results on the searchpage, so I want to click on the link whose URL has the product number that I'm searching for (which is `000471` in this case). I want to select the `<a>` element which contains that string in the `href` attribute.

Here's what I've tried:

```
inp = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchResults']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th/a[contains(@href,'"+str3+"')]")
inp.click()
```

where `str3` has the value `000471` in this case. But I keep getting `NoSuchElementException`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no string "searchResults" in the page you linked, so no XPath expression using it will ever find anything.

Comment: I forgot to add the page from where I am actually searching: http://www.ema.europa.eu/ema/index.jsp?curl=pages%2Fmedicines%2Flanding%2Fepar_search.jsp&mid=WC0b01ac058001d124&searchTab=searchByKey&alreadyLoaded=true&isNewQuery=true&status=Authorised&status=Withdrawn&status=Suspended&status=Refused&keyword=abilify&keywordSearch=Submit&searchType=name&taxonomyPath=&treeNumber=&searchGenericType=generics

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably cause by elements which are inserted into the source code viewer or inspector when rebuilding the table. The `tbody` tag is usually inserted in the code when it doesn't actually exist in the real source.

You can eliminate the unnecessary steps in your XPath, if you can still obtain a unique location path to the data you wish to select. This might be sufficient:

```
//*[@id='searchResults']//a[contains(@href,'000471')]
```

If the other steps are still necessary, you can try it *without* the `tbody`.

**Update** I also noticed that your search page declares a namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
    ...
```

Automatic registration of default namespaces is implementation dependent. XPath requires all selectors to be qualified with a namespace. If your selenium implementation doesn't do that, you need to either register a namespace/prefix mapping, and prefix all elements in the namespace (ex: `//h:table/h:tr/h:td`) or *ignore* the namespace, using wildcards and comparing the local name in a predicate.

If the namespace is keeping you from selecting the node, you can ignore it with this expression:

```
//*[@id='searchResults']//*[local-name() = 'a'][contains(@href,'000471')]
```

Comment: I tried the page with both the XPath that @helderdarocha provided as well as the trimmed `//a[contains(@href,'000471')]` and both work! Something else must be going on - post more of your code.